# How to install TensorFlow for dummies on Windows?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

**Am new to programming** and have no idea even how to install TensorFlow, as it's not a one-step process.

Can any give or at least refer to a definitive tutorial for installing Tensor Flow in Windows.

Thank You! 
:D

Comment: what have you tried until now? I mean have you followed the instructions on the official website?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you have looked up so far, but this was the first result doing a google search.

Link: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

Answer (score 0):

In windows, Tensorflow only works in 64 bit and with python 3.5. I don't know what you have installed but following the code below exactly will create a 64-bit python 3.5 environment and install Tensorflow in it for you. To activate or deactivate this environment, you would simply type :

```
set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=
conda create --name name_of_your_created_environment python=3.5
activate name_of_your_created_environment
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1 sets to a 32-bit environment whilst CONDA_FORCE_32BIT= sets to a 64-bit environment.

To deactivate this new environment and return to the original environment you use daily, just type:

```
deactivate name_of_your_created_environment
```

You can always return to this environment to use Tensorflow by re-typing:

```
activate name_of_your_created_environment
```